# Remembering the key randomly selected by the program

Tags: python

I am making a program to help me memorize my Latin. So far I have made a dictionary and found the code used to select a random key in the dictionary. I am a bit confused as to how I should follow on.

```
import random
words = {'son' : 'filius', 'garden' : 'hortus', 'work' : 'laboro'}
guess = input("How do you say " + (random.choice(list(words.keys()))) + " in Latin")
```

So after I use the `random.choice` feature will the program remember what key it used? If it does not then how can I make the program remember it?

Comment: Have you considered storing the random choice in a variable, then using that to find the translation using the random value as a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
words = {'son' : 'filius', 'garden' : 'hortus', 'work' : 'laboro'}
word = (random.choice(list(words.keys())))
guess = raw_input("How do you say " +  word + " in Latin\n")
if guess == words[word]:
    print "Correct"
else:
    #DO ELSE
```

Something like this maybe.

Answer (score 0):

you just store it in a variable (e.g. `choice`):

```
import random
words = {'son' : 'filius', 'garden' : 'hortus', 'work' : 'laboro'}
choice = random.choice(list(words.keys()))
guess = input("How do you say {} in Latin?".format(choice))
```

or you can store the english and the latin word with:

```
eng, lat = random.choice(list(words.items()))
```